# Как добавить класс к первому dom элементу react компонента?

Tags: reactjs

Как имея react компонент получить первый dom компонент и добавить ему css класс?

```
 const component = (<Comp {...this.props} myParam={param} />)

 return component;
```

Вот тут Comp приходит из props, и неизвестно где он определен и сколько их может быть и какая там структура. Но важно чтобы его первый dom элемент имел определенный css класс на странице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обратиться к DOM элементу через `ref`, предварительно его задав. ref также можно передавать через props.

```js
class Comp extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {
    this.props.compRef.current.classList.add("mystyle");
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
       <div ref={this.props.compRef}>
         <p>SomeText</p>
         <button 
           type="button"
           onClick={this.onClick}
         >Button</button>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.compRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <Comp
          compRef={this.compRef}
      />
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.mystyle {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Доступа к классу Comp нету.  Comp классов 4000 разных, входить в каждый и вешать там ref не вариант.

Comment: а если при размещении 4000 элементов просто давать им уникальные id и по id назначать класс?

Comment: и `const component = (<div className="myClass"><Comp {...this.props} myParam={param} /></div>)` не подойдет?